# Does SO points scoring system need to be reviewed

Tags: discussion

Although SO's scoring system is quite well. But it works highly in the favour of those questions/answers which were asked in early days of SO (almost all of highest ranked posts are from 2008/09).

So what if someone encountered similar problem (or came up with a similar or may be better answer) but is scored quite lower (its almost logarithmic scale attenuation in points for posts beyond 2011)

Maybe someone would draw an analogy between posts on SO and Research papers where old work gets more citations as later ones build on it, but its not the case here. A question which was asked in 2008/09 may have been asked by someone (on some other platform) decades ago and similarly some answers also link to some other platforms which have already answered this thing

Yes this scoring system is for SO but again, doesn't it need to be reviewed as old posts are getting bit unfair advantage (to me).

Comment: Thanks for downvoting but "Will the Real Batman please stand up?" and show why chosen to downvote it without caring to answer/comment it?

Comment: It is not required to leave a comment when down voting. You can assume on meta the down vote means: No, don't review the points scoring system.

Comment: Relevant reading about votes on meta: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Answer (score 12):

The point of scoring questions and answers is to indicate the usefulness and quality of those posts.

It is *not* to provide a level playing field where everyone is entitled to as much reputation as the highest-scoring user. If someone posted the same answer as you, but five years earlier, then that poster has an advantage of five years' worth of votes.

That is logical, and fair.

It seems like this is the umpteenth incarnation of *"It is so hard for newcomers to gain much reputation quickly"*, where the problem actually is that most newcomers simply aren't that good in providing top-quality answers that help many people.

Related:

- [How to gain reputation for a newcomer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129846/how-to-gain-reputation-for-a-newcomer)
- [What is the best way to increase my reputation and privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146472/what-is-the-best-way-to-increase-my-reputation-and-privileges)
- [How do I gain reputation as a new user and novice programmer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156115/how-do-i-gain-reputation-as-a-new-user-and-novice-programmer)

My point being: reputation indicates how many people found your posts useful. If you're a newcomer, or haven't posted much, you won't gain much reputation, and I don't think there needs to be anything changed about that.